# Unusual grid with Ajax Load More

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, wordpress

I would like to create an unusual grid using the [Ajax Load More](https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/) plugin. The plugin creates a standard list of posts, and I'd like to render the list with rows alternating between 4 and 3 items wide.

How can this be done?

So far in CSS I've set 25% width for the `li`'s to create a 4-wide row, but since the plugin uses AJAX for loading more content, it's screwing up my JS counter.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Just make sure the correct number of posts go into the rows.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

.row:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}

.post {
  height: 50px;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) .post {
  width: 25%;
}

.row:nth-child(even) .post {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="row">
    <li class="post">Post</li>
    <li class="post">Post</li>
    <li class="post">Post</li>
    <li class="post">Post</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="row">
    <li class="post">Post</li>
    <li class="post">Post</li>
    <li class="post">Post</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="row">
    <li class="post">Post</li>
    <li class="post">Post</li>
    <li class="post">Post</li>
    <li class="post">Post</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="row">
    <li class="post">Post</li>
    <li class="post">Post</li>
    <li class="post">Post</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that's it. Just the problem is this script have it's own HTML structure that is <ul><li> </li></ul>

Comment: Working with <ul> and <li> now

Comment: I meant I cannot create rows and my own HTML at all. It's just <ul> and just line of li

Comment: If it's just one <li>, how is a single post presented? Is that a div?

Comment: No, no. It's ul with li with all of blog posts. It can be infinite. Look up how does this script works.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to explore using ALM's PHP variables, so that you can define an item's CSS class according to what position it is in a query. With classes acting as markers (breakpoints), then you might have an easier time rendering unusual rows.

With the variables you can get both the total number of query items and the current item's position number within the entire query, and in theory do something with it. Using this data you may be able to identify every 3rd and then every 4th item, in addition to using some global PHP variable(s) to keep track.

https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/docs/variables/